# Identify a story about running from a relentless chasing machine or bot

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to identify a story I read decades ago that I visualize this way and often think about when I am cross country running:

There is a machine that I visualize as round, with some way to destroy people (such as injecting them with something) that relentlessly chases the protagonist to run him down.

I seem to associate the name Ruun with the story.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What short story has a ball chasing a researcher to add him to its collection?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33902/what-short-story-has-a-ball-chasing-a-researcher-to-add-him-to-its-collection)

Answer (score 6):

This is "[The Ruum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ruum)" by Arthur Porges

Per wikipedia:

> *"A shape-shifting, indestructible robot—a "Type H-9 Ruum"—is accidentally left behind on earth during the age of the dinosaurs by
> visiting aliens, and not recovered because their ship is destroyed in
> a battle. The Ruum's work is collecting different species of animals
> within a 30 mile radius, weighing 160 pounds (give or take 15 pounds)
> and preserving them in a state of suspended animation for later
> retrieval."*

A full copy of the text (complete with illustrations) is available [here](http://mrcampbellrocks.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/The-Ruum-by-Arthur-Porges-Full-Text.pdf).

[image]

You might also be interested to hear that the story had a sequel called "[A specimen for the queen](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?74160)".