# Short story anthology, one story was about a leathery alien thing that had a fight with a bear

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to find a sci-fi anthology I owned as a child from the early 80s/late 70s.  I think it was published in the UK by St Michael (Marks & Spencer), but possibly not as I can't find it under that publisher.

There is a St Michael sci-fi anthology called *Beyond the Stars: Tales of Adventure in Time and Space*, but that's not it as I think the book I remember contained the Ray Bradbury story "A Sound of Thunder", though memory does play tricks...

As I recall, one of the other stories was about a leathery alien thing that sort of rolled along and at one point had a fight with a bear (I think).  I recall that the alien thing in the story was sort of oval and leathery and that it used a knife blade to kill the bear.  I think the story or possibly the alien thing's name began with an "O". Some of the stories had illustrations.  Unfortunately I can't remember anything about the other stories in the collection.  Does anyone know what the anthology might be?

Comment: Could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) and [edit] in anything else? For example, do you know what any of the other stories were about? Were there any memorable plot elements?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First off, I believe the story you described, about the leathery alien thing that rolls along and hunts bears (among other critters) is ["The Ruum"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?74067), a short story by [Arthur Porges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Porges), first published in [*The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction*, October 1953](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?61375+c); you can read it for free at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v005n04_1953-10/Fantasy__Science_Fiction_v005n04_1953-10#page/n25). It paralyzes and preserves its victims instead of killing them, and it's called a "ruum" which does not start with an "O", but I think it's close enough to your description, considering that you read it 40 years ago. For more about "The Ruum", see my (unaccepted) answer to [this old question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/178728/story-about-an-alien-that-freezes-animals-but-keeps-them-alive).

So we're looking for an anthology containing both "The Ruum" and Bradbury's "A Sound of Thunder", that was published in the UK sometime around 1980. My guess is [*The Stars and Under*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?367488), edited by [Edmund Crispin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmund_Crispin) and published by [Faber and Faber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faber_and_Faber); perhaps the 1975 edition:

[image]

It was published in the right place around the right time, and it contains those two stories, but I don't know if it has any illustrations.

Comment: I think you are indeed correct  and yes, the story I described is The Ruum by Arthur Porges (I've just quickly re-read it).  Many thanks for taking the time to answer - much appreciated